# How to retrieve ArrayList<CustomObject> with Volley and put it in PullToRefreshListView?

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, arraylist

I am actually working on a ListView. I read data from a server and I use Volley to do this.
I have a News class who has a title, a description and a picture.

I have my function `getNewsList(Context context)` which I want to return an ArrayList.

But I return a null value.

Here is my function :

```
    public ArrayList<News> getNewsList(final Context context) {

    apws = new APWSManager(context, new APWSRequestState() {

        @Override
        public void customURLFinishedDownload(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("RESPONSE LISTVIEWPARSER : ", response);
            try {
                JSONArray   array = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject myJson = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    parseJsonItem(myJson);
                    //listCount += INTERVALLE;
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void customURLFailedDownload(String errorMessage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("ERROR REQUEST : ", errorMessage.toString());
        }
    });
    HashMap<String, String> mapGet = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapGet.put("&start=", String.valueOf(listCount));
    mapGet.put("&end=", String.valueOf((listCount+INTERVALLE)));

    apws.callAPWSRequest("getnews", mapGet, null, TypeMethod.GET, true);

    return m_ListItem;
}
```

When I get my response, I parse it with my function `parseJsonItem(JSONObject object)` to get values "title", "picture" and "description".

Here is my function :

```
    private void parseJsonItem(JSONObject myItem) {
    try {
        Log.i("NEWS " + myItem.getString("title"), myItem.toString());
        mNews = new News(myItem.getString("title"), myItem.getString("value_out"), myItem.getString("picture"));

        m_ListItem.add(mNews);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

My problem is the next : I implement a custom ListView who's called PullToRefreshListView.

I have three steps in that Object : the first load, the onLoadMore and the onRefresh. I retrieve correctly my data in my ListView, you can see the result here :

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img842/6004/8wi4.png

I have two booleans : firstLoad to know if I load for the first time, and isRefreshing to know if my ListView is refreshing or not.
I need to implement it in my ListView. I have a constant value 'INTERVALLE = 5' because i am loading data 5 by 5.
My function `getNewsList` return null value for my ArrayList. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong and anyone used onLoadMore and onRefresh and can explain to me?

Thank you guys !

Comment: Your thread isn't blocking and getNewsList is returning before your server can answer...?

Comment: @ElDuderino I don't think so because getNewsList is the first function I call. And if you look the picture, you see that I retrieve an answer from the server